# Traverse an array starting from a specific column index

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

I need to traverse the array and add from mid column index to the east of the array and get the sum of the values.

Then traverse the array from mid column index to the west of the array and get the sum of the values.

Then add both to find the sum together. Repeat this for n number of rows and find the optimal path.

I am really lost on how to start calculations from a mid point.

Answer (score 0):

`int mid = (firstIndex + lastIndex)/2` should give you the middle if an odd length array and `int mid = ((firstIndex + lastIndex)/2) - 1` for an even length array – `array[mid]`.

From here, you could simply use loops to add up the numbers from each side and get the side by using the `mid` variable in your loop's condition.

```java
int leftSum = 0;
int rightSum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= mid; i++) { //from first index to middle of array
    leftSum += array[i];
}

for(int i = mid; i <= array.length - 1; i++) { //from middle to end of array
    rightSum += array[i];
}

int totalSum = leftSum + rightSum;
```

This would be for a one-dimensional array. It sounds like you are talking about using a two-dimensional array. In this case, you would use nested loops to get from rows to columns–where the outer for loop is the rows and the inner would be to determine the columns.

Comment: Yes it is about a 2D array

Comment: @unknowntotheworld In that case, you would definitely use a nested for loop for each side. You can reference the middle column by using ```array[i][mid]```.